# What does scanf do when it encounters a space in the format string?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    scanf(" %d ", &a);
    printf("\n%d", a);
    return 0;  
}
```

When I give an input and press enter, it waits for another value and after giving 2nd value it's showing the output what I gave it the beginning. Why?  What does `scanf()` do when it encounters a space in the format string?

Comment: Remove space after %d.

Answer (score 4):

When there is a blank in the format string, [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) consumes zero or more white space characters until it comes across a non-white-space character.  Newlines are white space.

Therefore, especially for interactive input, trailing white space in a format string is a bad idea!  In your code, remove the trailing space.  (Note that you could type anything, not just another number, after the first number and the code will report on the first number you enter; the extra data is available to another read operation, even though your program does not actually read it.)

Most conversion specifications ignore leading white space too.  The exceptions are `%c`, `%n` and `%[...]` (the last being the scanset conversion specification).

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
scanf(" %d ",&a);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

otherwise `scanf` will wait until you pass a non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/):

> The function will read and ignore any whitespace
>   characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character
>   (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters --
>   see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any
>   quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including
>   none).

So change

```
scanf(" %d ",&a);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```