# Undefined behaviour after multiple calls to a print function

Tags: c, assembly

I'm writing a basic compiler and the code generated does not work as intended. 
I'm using a naive graph coloring algorithm to allocate variables in registers based on their liveness. 
The problem is that the generated assembly code seems perfectly fine, but, at some point, it produces undefined behaviour.

If, instead of using registers to store variables, I just use the stack, everything works fine.
I also discovered that I can't use the `%edx` register around an `imull` instruction and I wondered if something similar is happening right now with `%ebx` and `%ecx`.
I compile the code using `gcc -m32 "test.s" runtime.c -o test`, where `runtime.c` is a helper C file containing the print and input functions. 
I've also tried to remove parts of the program (every print except the last one) and then the last print will work.
If I call a single print function before the last call it won't work.

The `runtime.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int input() {
    int num;
    char term;
    scanf("%d%c", &num, &term);
    return num;
}

void print_int_nl(int i) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Source file:

```py
a = 10
b = input()
c = - 10
d = -input()
print a
print b
print c
print d
```

Generated assembly code:
https://pastebin.com/ChSRbWgt

After compiling the .s file and running it using the console (`./test`) it asks for 2 input (as intended).
I give it 1 and 2. 
Then the output is:

```
10
1
-10
1415880
```

instead of

```
10
1
-10
-2
```

Comment: Your generated code likely doesn't preserve the registers that the calling convention says should be preserved. AFAIR, if you preserve everything except `eax` and `edx`, you should be OK. For more details see e.g. [Calling conventions for different C++ compilers and operating systems by Agner Fog](https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf).

Comment: By reading the Register Usage section, it seems that only `%ebx` needs to be preserved (callee-save) and I do preserve it. But, correct me if i'm wrong, it seems that I should also preserve `%eax` and `%edx` because they might receive the return value of some instructions (i.e. `%edx` gets replaced when using `imull`)

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze   1. C != C++. 2. Compilers know what to preserve. It is tested by milions of developers

Comment: @P__J__: The OP is writing their own compiler, which is possible getting it wrong.  This isn't a [mcve], though, because they're not showing the generated asm.

Comment: @P__J__ but I'm writing my own compiler so probably I've missed something that prevents it from working

Comment: @Riccardo Yes, printf() can trash some caller-save registers easily, so, you need to save them before the call.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze yes, the problem was exactly that, now everything works fine! If you want submit it as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to observe the calling convention (see e.g. [Calling conventions for different C++ compilers and operating systems by Agner Fog](https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf)).

Namely, there are caller-save and callee-save registers in the convention for your C compiler.

Your generated code needs to preserve the callee-save registers in order to be able to return to its C caller.

Similarly, printf() will preserve the callee-save registers, but it can trash the caller-save registers, meaning that if your generated code calls printf(), it will need to preserve the caller-save registers across the calls to printf() or any other C function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the input buffer after your first input the buffer still contains the newline character i'd recommend this :

```
int input() {
  int num;
  char term;
  scanf("%d %c", &num, &term);

  return num;
}
```

Comment: `scanf`'s `%d` conversion ([like most others, but not `%c`, `%n`, or `%[`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515622/what-does-scanf-do-when-it-encounters-a-space-in-the-format-string)) already discards leading whitespace, so this is pointless.  See   [Why is adding a leading space in a scanf format string recommended?](//stackoverflow.com/q/26391465) for discussion of cases like some fixed text before a conversion, where a space before *that* is helpful.

Comment: You never whitespace before `%d`, because it discards whitespace on its own.  Only `%c` (and character-range and `%n`) don't do that.  The space *after* it, before `%c`, is potentially useful, though, because it's `%c`.  Your loop that discarded characters up to and including a newline is probably not needed (and would discard the whole first line of input.)  Also, IDK if the OP was using `%c` to eat trailing newlines;  maybe.  In that case, `" %c"` will instead eat the first character after the whitespace.

Comment: `scanf("%d %c", &num, &term);` has the undesired side effect of requiring a non white space character to be typed after the number -> `scanf("%d%*c", &num);` will consume the pending character, most likely a newline or a space.  Even better: `scanf("%d%*1[\n]", &num);` will consume the pending newline if any.